# How to use "Read Aloud" extension in notepad tab (firefox, chrome, etc)?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, html, firefox-extensions

I'm trying to use the "Read Aloud" extension with a notepad tab. The notepad tab I open with this code:

```
data:text/html, <html contenteditable>
```

But, the extension throws an error:

```
"Missing host permission for the tab".

"cannot access contexts of the page. extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host"
```

Is there a way to make the extension work with a notepad tab?